# Problem with Matlab Live Editor tables format display

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have a problem with an script I'm writing in the Live Editor in Matlab.
The default format for tables is like this image:
[image]

But after about 420 lines of code the output format of the tables what I'm getting is the like the "Command Window" table format:

[image]

I'm using the same code for generate both of them:

```
array2table()
```

but for some strange reason the output format is different and useless for exporting to a document because of the inconsistency of the format.
Apart for the fact of the first output format is navigably to the end of rows or columns, but the second one you can only see the displayed part of the table.
I'd appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue.